# Two columns layout using one container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Look at the screen below (I'm using **Bootstrap**):

[image: Screenshot]

Adding a padding can solve this problem but it is not responsive for mobile devices. Is there a better way to this?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary text-white ">
        <h1>header 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary text-white ">

        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus ex plicabo.20
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please post your current HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below upsated html

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 bg-primary"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary text-white ">

        <h1>header 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">

        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3"></div>
      <div class="col-md-3 bg-primary text-white ">

        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus explicabo.20</p>

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h1>Header 2</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro laboriosam est obcaecati veniam optio natus officiis tempora eum odit, cum dolores similique inventore neque? Error id eligendi ducimus, natus ex plicabo.20
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome, please don't forget to consider it as answer :)